# I installed pandas but it is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have PyCharm 18 and I installed pandas version 0.22.0. When i import it it is not working,

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

datas = pd.DataFrame({
    "fsfsd": ["fff", "fss"],
    "ddfs": ["fsdfsd", "fdfsfs"]
})

print(datas)
```

but when it executes it gives me the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/PC18/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\PC18\pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
    datas = pd.DataFrame({
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pls help; thanks

Comment: Try reinstalling pandas

Comment: How exactly did you install `pandas`?

Comment: throw the project interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trials and errors, it seems like it is a version issue with Pandas 0.22.0, because it worked on PyCharm 2016.2.1 rather than PyCharm 2018

Answer (score 6):

The problem is due to the name of your script "`pandas.py`" you can't have in your current folder files call `pd` or `pandas`, etc...

In general avoid name for script, variable, etc... that are also use for library, module, function, etc...

Comment: Nice catch of the script name.

Comment: Wow ! I completely missed this information. Nice one

Comment: it's not about names. I resaved it in other name but the problem still exist

Comment: @Jalalrka, if you are sure there is no file at all with conflicting name in your folder, you may considering unistall and re-install pandas... `pip unsinstall pandas` and then `pip install panda` but it's very strange because you do not have error when you `import pandas as pd`...

Comment: go to your terminal and write the command `pip uninstall pandas` and press enter. Then write the command `pip install pandas`

Comment: in the CMD, I went to C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts, then I typed pip uninstall pandas and pip install panda and it installed it but have the same errors :(. is it right?